# Select rows that begin with a pattern in R

Tags: r, design-patterns

I am working with an R database, which has 3 columns, named index, NAICS and HS2. The head of the database looks like this:

```
> head(base_sec)
        Index  NAICS    HS2
1   0.4074128   1111 010110
2   0.2858026  11111 010190
3   0.1103720  11112 010210
4  -0.8084129 111120 010290
5   0.5376827 111130 010310
6   0.6021241  11114 010391
```

Well, I want to select the rows in which NAICS column meets a given condition. More specifically, I want to select the rows in which NAICS begins with any of these values:

```
  list=c("111","112", "113","114",
          "115", "211", "212", "213",
         "3111", "3112", "3113", "3114",
         "3115", "3116","3117", "3118",
          "3119", "321")
```

Do you know how to solve this problem? any idea is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions work here. Ultimately, we want something like:

```
grepl("^(11112|11113|11114)", x$NAICS)
```

where we are interested in three strings *starting* the `NAICS` identifiers. (I've shortened it here for brevity.

Your data, truncated a little for example:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
        Index  NAICS    HS2
1   0.4074128   1111 010110
2   0.2858026  11111 010190
3   0.1103720  11112 010210
4  -0.8084129 111120 010290
5   0.5376827 111130 010310
6   0.6021241  11114 010391")

l <- c("11112", "11113", "11114")
```

To programmatically make that:

```
paste0("^(", paste(l, collapse="|"), ")")
# [1] "^(11112|11113|11114)"
```

So we can do:

```
grepl(paste0("^(", paste(l, collapse="|"), ")"), x$NAICS)
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

and ultimately

```
x[grepl(paste0("^(", paste(l, collapse="|"), ")"), x$NAICS),]
#        Index  NAICS   HS2
# 3  0.1103720  11112 10210
# 4 -0.8084129 111120 10290
# 5  0.5376827 111130 10310
# 6  0.6021241  11114 10391
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
out = x[substr(x$NAICS, 0, 3) %in% list | substr(x$NAICS, 0, 4) %in% list,]
```

Hope it helps.